# Adding duplicate records?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have a form like user details, when click on new record I'm calling save method in same page. It's working fine after i refresh the page again record is inserting as duplicate how I avoid this type of issue?

my code is:

mynewtemplate.phtml

```
<form method="post"  >
    <div class="mycustomstyle">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="nom">First Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="prenom">Last Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="nom">Telephone Number</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">
                        <button name="btn_submit" type="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getUrl('practice/index/new') ?>';" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('New Record') ?></span></span></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){
        echo 'Calling Save Method';
        echo $this->Save();
    }

    ?>

</form>
```

and my code in block->template.php

```
public function Save()
    {

        $fn = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('nom');
        $ln = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('prenom');
        $tn = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('telephone');

        if(isset($fn)&& ($fn!='') && isset($ln)&& ($ln!='') && isset($tn)!='')
            Mage::getModel('test/test')->_save($fn,$ln,$tn);


    }
```

my design:

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: either mark telephone field in database as unique column, so that duplicate data won't be stored.
or do it using MVC approach.

Comment: hi shathish, can you give me a simple validation example for this?

Comment: there is no need for validation, if u mark the mysql table column (which holds telephone number) as "UNIQUE", then duplicate values won't be added to it (when refreshed and also when trying to insert same value again). Magento will handle the mysql error in this case.

Comment: k If I want to make those 3 fields are required, then how to make? give me steps..

Comment: go through these links `http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/validate-your-input-magento-style/` and  `http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/javascript-prototype-form-validation/`

Comment: @ManojKumar.. if you want to use 3 fields are required then you can use magento input validation .. https://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Comment: @ManojKumar could you post your code as a working example?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't save things in a template file.
Make your form submit to a controller and handle the save in there.
To avoid re-sending the form, in the controller action where you handle the save, after saving the data do a redirect. It can be to the same page, but this way you don't have anything in `$_POST`.